# d3 pie chart json variable from rails

Tags: javascript, json, ruby-on-rails-3, charts, d3.js

i have this rails variable:

```
data = [{:data=>"Military / Neutral", :frequency=>1}, {:data=>"Former Armed Forces / Neutral", :frequency=>1}, {:data=>"Journalist / Neutral", :frequency=>5}, {:data=>"Journalist / ", :frequency=>46}]
```

json object:

```
data.to_json = [{"data":"Military / Neutral","frequency":1},{"data":"Former Armed Forces / Neutral","frequency":1},{"data":"Journalist / Neutral","frequency":5},{"data":"Journalist / ","frequency":46}]
```

i want to give it to my pie chart:

```
var pie = new Chart({
width: 1000,
height: 400,
title: "Neutral vs Non-Neutral (Pie Graph),
position: "#graphs",
margin: {
  top: 20,
  bottom: 30,
  right: 20,
  left: 40
   }
 },     
 <%= data.to_json  %>
).Pie().draw();
```

but i have an error:

```
SyntaxError: invalid property id 
[{&quot;data&quot;:&quot;Military / Neutral&quot;,&quot;freque
```

it is not escaping the `"` (double quote)? why?

Comment: [This article](http://jfire.io/blog/2012/04/30/how-to-securely-bootstrap-json-in-a-rails-view/) may help.

Comment: thanks, it is helping for small json object i added `<%= data.to_json.html_safe %>` but not for big ones